# How do you receive data back from a GET/POST request to a Cloud Run container through Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I followed the tutorial here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run in order to setup my hosted website to be able to call a Google Cloud Run container I have previously deployed (written in Python).  This container accepts both GET and POST requests, and works as expected when tested otherwise.

When I rewrote a URL in my website to call this function (I used `"source": "/api/**"` in my Firebase.json file), the console logs that the URL is being redirected successfully and the Cloud Run container is being executed.  However, there seems to be no way for me to retrieve any response from these requests.  Thus, if I am serving my website using `firebase serve` and enter the URL http://localhost:5000/api into my browser, I get the '404 Not Found' error, even though the container is being called in the background.

Does anyone know how to call a Google Cloud Run container in this manner, and retrieve a response back via the same rewritten URL?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying that the container deployed to Cloud Run actually executes in response to the request, and you can see that for sure in the Cloud Run logs?  But the response never makes it back through the emulator to the client?  It might just be that the emulator is broken, because this should all work when deployed to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Yes exactly, the same thing happens when I `firebase deploy` too, however.

Comment: On closer inspection, I just realized that the GET requests being made in this manner are adding on pieces to the URL being called.  E.g. if I call localhost:5000/api, the request gets sent to the Cloud Run as cloud-run-url/api, which will of course result in an error.  Do you know how this could be fixed?  Is there something I should change in the firebase.json rewrite statement?  Thanks again.

Comment: You can't make your container respond to the URL that it's been given?

Comment: I can't make firebase call the container's base URL.  Otherwise, I could just allow the container to respond to this additional URL, but I'd prefer if the base URL worked too.